# Facebook posts retrieval in android

Tags: android, facebook, post, feed

I am trying to retrieve the facebook's latest post in my android app by using the code given below. But it gives me only my shares and comments. I want to get these as well as my messages which I post on my status, but it always comes as null.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("format", "json");
params.putString("access_token",sp.getString("access_token",null));
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", params);
JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
JSONArray jsonArray = json.optJSONArray("data");

if(jsonArray != null) {
i=0;
String tempName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("from");
String tempId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
String story = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("story");
String msg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("message");
}
```

Here, if I post some text on my status then also 'msg' is null.

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to have the "read_stream" permission before you can access non-public posts. See the Connections section of the [User API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for what other permissions you may need for other methods.

You can try out your requests first using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: it has all the perssion but Iwant to read the real-time data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Once I grant my app read_stream permissions, every time I make a /me/feed request, I can see the latest posts I make.

Comment: I can get all the content except message field